# Show plain password in joomla

Tags: joomla

I would need a readout of joomlas user password in plain style to give special users the ability to send a mail in a custom module with login details like:

https://mydomain/login?user=testuser
password = testuserpassword

For that reason I need the plain passowrd out of the DB. Is there a way to show/read out password from joomla-db in plain style?

Thx in advanced!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but please, don't do that. I can't think of a single instance where storing/retrieving plain text password doesn't end bad.

Comment: In no way whatsoever is this a good idea. Besides that, it's not possible to do so as the passwords are stored in the database as a BCrypt hash and cannot be reverted back to plain text.

Comment: Thx for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Joomla saves the passwords in the database using a one way encryption mechanism, which means that you cannot know what the password is.

I am sure what you're doing can be done in a different method - if you want to login users automatically once they click on a link then you can have a different authentication plugin that will use a random, unique, one-time-use, and time-sensitive hash that will be associated with a Joomla user account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plugin with function after joomla user save
you need to store password in another table with user id and then you can use with sql query to get  password.

Comment: Thx - I searched for a solution to rehash the passwords on the fly, but if this is not possible it would be to much risk to save the passwords in plain-txt in another table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea for the following reasons:

- email is sent in plain text
- email often is stored on several systems along the way to your mailbox
- email often is stored on your computer in plain text or other unencrypted format
- many copies may exist in many places, even after "deletion"
- even encrypted email can be broken in to, given enough computing time
- your account's security may have been compromised even before you read your email (changing the password will not help in this case)

However, you definitely can email the user their password upon initial registration by going to *Global Configuration > Users* and setting *Send Password* to "Yes" (default setting in Joomla 3.x).

[image: Send Password]

If you are looking for a way to send this password after the registration event, as others have mentioned, you are out of luck. What Joomla! provides is a secure password reset functionality to [reset a password](https://docs.joomla.org/Resetting_a_user_password) to something the user can remember. This will be the best approach for you, as well.

---

Resources: [Sending Passwords in Email](http://www.thebitmill.com/articles/password_email.html), [Stop Joomla Sending Passwords in Emails](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/passwords-emails/#comment-2592823272)